# React Router not rendering component, says return statement missing

Tags: reactjs, router

Im geting an error like this: **Uncaught Error: Route(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing.**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, ReactDom} from 'react-router-dom'
import ProductsDisplay from './ProductsDisplay'
import Home from './Home'
import Contact from './Contact'

const Main = () => {
    return (
    <main>

            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                <Route exact path="/monitors" render={() => {<ProductsDisplay productCategory="monitors"/>}}/>
                <Route exact path="/computers" render={() => {<ProductsDisplay productCategory="computers"/>}}/>
            </Switch>

    </main>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

I am certain the return statement is in all components, any ideas what this can be?

Comment: This can happen if your component is not correctly imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the method passed to render prop. Try removing `{}` brackets like this

```
<Route exact path="/monitors" render={() => <ProductsDisplay productCategory="monitors"/>}/>
<Route exact path="/computers" render={() => <ProductsDisplay productCategory="computers"/>}/>
```

Or write `return` in that method like this

```
<Route exact path="/monitors" render={() => {return <ProductsDisplay productCategory="monitors"/>}}/>
<Route exact path="/computers" render={() => {return <ProductsDisplay productCategory="computers"/>}}/>
```

Comment: That did it thanks! RIYAJ KHAN's answer also worked, but I can only accept 1 answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Return statement is missing in `monitors` and `computers` route render property.You need to return `React Component` or `React element`.

```
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
<Route exact path="/monitors" render={() => {return <ProductsDisplay productCategory="monitors"/>}}/>
<Route exact path="/computers" render={() => {return <ProductsDisplay productCategory="computers"/>}}/>
</Switch>
```

or with ECMA6 default return syntax

```
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
<Route exact path="/monitors" render={() => (<ProductsDisplay productCategory="monitors"/>)}/>
<Route exact path="/computers" render={() => (<ProductsDisplay productCategory="computers"/>)}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: I thought the ES6 part was the arrow function (which is used in both examples), not the implicit `return` without `{`.